# Probability of selecting spades or an ace from a deck of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

> Find the probability that given $i$ cards from a deck of $52$, $j$ of them are spades and $k$ of them are aces, where $1\leq i\leq 52, \max\{i-39,0\}\leq j\leq \min\{i, 13\},$ and $\max\{i-48, 0\}\leq k\leq \min\{i, 4\}.$

In the general case, obviously the number of ways to select the $i$ cards is ${52\choose i}$. Define $P(A_1)$ to be the probability that $j$ spades are chosen and $P(A_2)$ the probability that $k$ aces are chosen.  To compute $P(A_1),$ we select the spades and then the nonspades, and similarly for $P(A_2)$. To compute $P(A_1\cap A_2),$ we consider the number of possibilities where there is an ace of spades or there is no ace of spades. Then $P(A_1) = \dfrac{{13\choose j}{39\choose i-j}}{{52\choose i}}, P(A_2) = \dfrac{{4\choose k}{48\choose i-k}}{{52\choose i}}, P(A_1\cap A_2) = \dfrac{{1\choose 1}{3\choose k-1}{12\choose j-1}{36\choose i-j-k+1} + {3\choose k}{12\choose j}{36\choose i-j-k}}{{52\choose i}}$, where ${a\choose b} = 0$ if $b < 0$ or $b > a$ for simplicity. So the desired probability is the result $P(A_1) + P(A_2)-P(A_1\cap A_2).$

> Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   Your reasoning and counting is correct.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(\spadesuit_j)&=\left.\tbinom {13}{j}\tbinom{39}{i-j}\middle/\tbinom{52}i\right.
\\[1ex]\mathsf P(A_k)&=\left.\tbinom{4}{k}\tbinom{48}{i-k}\middle/\tbinom{52}i\right.
\\[1ex]\mathsf P(A_k\cap\spadesuit_j)&=\left.\left[\tbinom 11\tbinom 3{k-1}\tbinom {12}{j-1}\tbinom{36}{i-j-k+1}+\tbinom10\tbinom 3k\tbinom{12}j\tbinom{36}{i-j-k}\right]\middle/\tbinom{52}i\right.
\\[1ex]\mathsf P(A_k\cup\spadesuit_j)&=\mathsf P(\spadesuit_j)+\mathsf P(A_k)-\mathsf P(A_k\cap\spadesuit_j)
\end{align}$$